# Why is the trunk link tagged on the frames?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, frame

Doesn't every frame have a VLAN identifier? So why is it labeled on the trunk link to identify the VLAN?
For example, in this image, computer A is in red VLAN and the switch detects this, so why re-tagging in the trunk link?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No – frames sent by regular devices on access ports have no VLAN tag whatsoever. The switch only "detects" their VLAN based on static configuration stored *in the switch itself* (i.e. each port's PVID parameter), not based on frame contents.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question correctly, but if you are referring to the `0/1`, `0/2`, `0/3` labels, you are confusing port labels with VLAN labels.

If you are referring to the colour of the connection between the switches, since the trunk is probable configured for more then one VLAN, a neutral colour was chosen (theoretically you could "paint" it in both VLAN colours). Grey does not mean the frame is retagged with the "grey VLAN tag".

All in laymen's terms of course...